# Curl error thrown for http POST to /session

Tags: php, laravel, chromium, headless, laravel-dusk

I installed Laravel Dusk for website testing. I tried every solution on Stackoverflow regarding this problem but nothing worked.

I need to run browser headless because I'm running tests on my Linux server.

Current version of chromedriver-linux is:

```
 ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux --v
ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429})
```

Current version of Chromium is:

```
 chromium-browser --version --no-sandbox
Chromium 90.0.4430.93 snap
```

When I run Dusk I get error:

```
Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"chrome","platformName":"linux","goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--headless","--disable-gpu","--no-sandbox"]}}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"linux","chromeOptions":{"args":["--headless","--disable-gpu","--no-sandbox"]}}}
```

Is there any way to resolve this? I tried by adding arguments `"--headless","--disable-gpu","--no-sandbox"` but unfortunately it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

friend!

I assume you are on Windows host with Homestead (Windows 10, Homestead 10 and Laravel 8). If not, I am not sure this answer will help. But this *just* helped me, literally, a few minutes ago, so I feel obliged.

1. `Dusk` appears not like `Chromium` and desires a full Chrome. So [lets install it](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-google-chrome-web-browser-on-ubuntu-20-04/):

```sh
cd ~
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

This will download the latest stable google chrome and install it.

2. Do make sure that you got your project's `vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/` folder is executable, as the docs suggest. So, in the root of your project:

```sh
chmod -R 0755 vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/
```

3. Make sure you got the latest chromium-driver installed:

```sh
php artisan dusk:chrome-driver --detect
```

3.1. *If* it will give you hard time (cannot rename, cannot move files, *yada-yada*) - it is probably because you have the driver already running, so exit Homestead and just

```sh
vagrant reload
```

return back to homestead and repeat 3 above.

4. Make sure you are able to curl your `APP_URL`. Let's say it is `laravel.app`:

```
curl http://laravel.app
```

If not, check `/etc/hosts`, you expect to see something like `127.0.0.1 laravel.app` - following our assumption about the URL. This is normally set by Homestead itself, when you provision a new site.

Voila.

```sh
php artisan dusk
```

was successful.

That fixed it for me.

I have spent exorbitant amount of time which could have been saved by a single line in docs "*If you are running Homestead on Windows, make sure to install Google Chrome*"

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for that. I mentioned linux in my post. Anyway I moved to Symfony Panther and it works :)